# Matplotlib - how to put multiple spaces between words in title string?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I try to plot a figure where the title is a raw string with multiple white space characters (eg. pressing space bar several times).

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax =plt.subplots()
title= r"Hello    This    Should    Have    LOTS    OF    Space"
fig.suptitle(title)
```

Result:
[image]

Am I doing something wrong? I recently reinstalled my whole OS, and I could have sworn that this worked before...

**edit:**
Matplotlib version: 3.7.1
Matplotlib Backend: Qt5Agg
Python version:     3.11.3

Comment: [Works for me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rnNgi.png). What version of matplotlib? Why does your chart have gridlines btw?

Comment: This is so weird. Just added my version information. No idea why it has gridlines, seems to be the default, I certainly did not turn them on manually.

Answer (score 1):

### Suspected cause: LaTeX plotting backend

The appearance of your plot, in particular, the fonts, seem to imply that you are using a [LaTeX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LaTeX) backend for plotting with matplotlib. To see if this is the case, maybe share what is your current backend. You can do so by using

```py
import matplotlib
print(matplotlib.get_backend())
```

If I am correct, this means your title string will be typeset in LaTeX, as well. And here is one of the properties of LaTeX: multiple successive spaces are interpreted as one space, and one has to do extra work to get more space(s).

If you wonder what I mean by "backend", see [here](https://matplotlib.org/stable/users/explain/backends.html). In short:

> Matplotlib can target different outputs, and each of these capabilities is called a backend; the "frontend" is the user facing code, i.e., the plotting code, whereas the "backend" does all the hard work behind-the-scenes to make the figure.

### Solution 1: Keep the backend, fix the spaces

So your actual question may boil down to: *How can I get a wider space between words in LaTeX?* For various options, see e.g. [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/88845/two-consecutive-spaces) on LaTeX Stack Exchange. For example, you can replace your spaces with `~`, which is a non-braking space in LaTeX and which will *not* be condensed into one for multiple successive spaces.

The following is a minimum working example that uses the [pgf backend](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/text/pgf.html) for plotting with LaTeX. Note that you need a LaTeX environment on your system if you want to reproduce it (this should not be a problem for OP, though). On my system (Linux Mint 21.2), in particular, I first had to install the `texlive-pictures` package for it to work:

```py
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

matplotlib.use("pgf")
matplotlib.rcParams.update({"pgf.texsystem": "pdflatex", "text.usetex": True})

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
title= r"Lots~~~~of~~~~space~~~~or    normal    space"
fig.suptitle(title)  # Result: "Lots    of    space    or normal space"

plt.savefig("test.pdf")  # Will be saved in the script's directory
```

### Solution 2: Fix the backend, keep the spaces

Alternatively, your actual question might be: *How can I turn off the LaTeX backend?* This might need to be done in different places, depending on how the current backend was chosen (I am not sure if this is an exhaustive list):

- See if your code has the line

  - `matplotlib.use(...)` or
  - `matplotlib.backend_bases.register_backend(...)`

  somewhere accidentally, and remove it.
- See if, when saving your figure, a different backend is currently chosen, e.g. via `plt.savefig(..., backend="pgf")`, and change the setting there.
- Maybe someone changed your default backend permanently via a configuration file; for that case, see [here](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/introductory/customizing.html#customizing-with-matplotlibrc-files).
- Maybe the wrong backend is set in your Python IDE; then check your IDE settings.

Comment: Thanks for the elaborate answers simon. print(matplotlib.get_backend()) gives me Qt5Agg.

Comment: @reloh100 That's kind of weird, because your figure really looks like a LaTeX plot. Did you once try to replace your spaces with "~"? Because if this works (i.e. produces spaces rather than "~" in your plot) it would even more confirm my suspicion.

Comment: Indeed, if I use FIG.suptitle(r"HELLO~WORLD") it prints a single space between hello and world. So the Latex backend is used even if the code itself states another backend? Do you think this is an Anaconda bug?

Comment: @reloh100 Might be a bug or otherwise some other hidden change of your backend setting. One more question: are you really plotting the figure or are you saving it to a file?

Comment: (by "really plotting", I mean showing it in the GUI or in a Jupyter notebook)

Comment: I use the Spyder IDE to plot it in an interactive window. But I also tried adding a plt.show() to the end of the script and ran it from the terminal using the same Anaconda Python. It's the same in both cases.

Comment: @reloh100 That is very weird then. Maybe it's really a bug in one of the conda packages, maybe in the Spyder version. I am not sure if I can help further at this point, I am sorry.

Comment: You have helped a lot! I will probably go the Anaconda forums and ask there, and I will refer to this discussion. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I found what caused this issue.
In one of my other scripts I had a line

```
plt.rcParams['text.usetex'] = True
```

I ran all my other scripts with the same Spyder kernel, so when that line was executed at some point, I changed the IDE's behavior.

This line seems to force matplotlib to interpret any strings as Latex code even when the printed backend is still Qt5Agg.

The error disappears when I run the script externally (i.e. without Spyder). I did test it before, but I must have done something wrong then as it works perfectly now.

Comment: At last :D Good catch!

Comment: Here is the corresponding doc: https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/text/usetex.html -- indeed it is possible to use LaTeX typesetting with the standard backend. I did not know that, otherwise I would have included it in my answer, as well. Seems like, we both learned something new today :)